# Buffer percentage - JWPlayer in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, jwplayer

https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/developer-guide/api/javascript_api_reference/#buffer I can get the percentage of video's current loaded amount. What is the corresponding function in objective C?

Also, can anyone please point me to a good documentation with playerState (explanation of all the possible player states) part adequately explained.

How do I identify if the buffering has stalled and the video can't be played anymore?

Went through links:
1.http://sdk.jwplayer.com/ios/docs/reference/Classes/JWPlayerController.html#//api/name/playerState

2.https://developer.jwplayer.com/sdk/ios/docs/developer-guide/embedding/embedding/